# Finding minimum array integer

Tags: php, algorithm, programming-challenge

I'm trying to solve one simple task and on first look it's working.
Any advice on how I can optimize this code will be appreciated.
A quick description of the task would be:
You have a file from which you read the integers.

The first line has two values:

1. The array width
2. The number of test cases

The second line has actual array values.
After that, you have \$N\$ rows all containing the array range which should be checked.

\$N =\$ the number of test cases.
[Here's a link to my code](http://jsfiddle.net/8zfsubhq/)

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$getFirstRow = fgets($handle);
$firstrow = explode(" ", $getFirstRow);
$firstrow1 = intval($firstrow[0]);
$firstrow2 = intval($firstrow[1]);

$getString = fgets($handle);
for ($z=0;$z<$firstrow2;$z++)
{
$getRange = fgets($handle);
$getRagearr = explode(" ", $getRange);
$i=intval($getRagearr[0]);
$j=intval($getRagearr[1]);
$arrResult = array();
$lane = explode(" ", $getString);
for ($p=$i;$p<=$j;$p++)
{
array_push($arrResult, $lane[$p]);
}
$result = min($arrResult);
echo $result.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Even if you provide a link to the code in a third party site, you must still include the relevant parts to be reviewed in the question itself. Please update your post to include the source code to be reviewed.

Comment: Ok sure, I will keep this in mind for future! I added the code into post

Comment: One tip, give your variables handy names, like your $firstrow2 should be $maxTestCases or something in that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should indent your code properly to make it more readable.

---

Posting PHP on JSFiddle is <s>apocalyptic insanity</s> a bad idea. JSFiddle is for JavaScript.
Use IDEOne for PHP Instead.

---

Your use of whitespace could be improved.

> ```
>  for ($z=0;$z<$firstrow2;$z++)
> ```

into: `for ($z = 0; $z < $firstrow2; $z++)`

---

Your variable naming is shortened, sometimes confusing, and flat out bad practice in places.
Transform them from `lowercase` to `camelCase`.

---

You don't even use `$firstrow1`, remove it.

---

`$getRagearr` sounds like a pirate themed narcotic. Perhaps `$getRangeArray` would be much clearer.

---

`$j=intval($getRagearr[1])`: what's wrong with good ole' fashioned `int()`?'

---

This is the result of all my suggestions:

```
$handle = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$getFirstRow = fgets($handle);
$firstRowArray = explode(" ", $getFirstRow);
$numOfTestCases = int($firstRow[1]);

$getString = fgets($handle);
for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfTestCases; $i++) {
    $getRange = fgets($handle);
    $getRangeArray = explode(" ", $getRange);
    $arrayWidth = int($getRangeArray[0]);
    $arrayLength = int($getRangeArray[1]);
    $arrayResult = array();
    $lane = explode(" ", $getString);
    for ($currentPos = $arrayWidth; $currentPos <= $arrayLength; $currentPos++) {
        array_push($arrayResult, $lane[$currentPos]);
    }
    $result = min($arrayResult);
    echo $result.PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

Other than that, your code looks well-structured.

Answer (score 3):

You read a line and split it by spaces multiple times.
To avoid such repeated logic, I suggest creating a function:

```
function read_line_as_array($fh) {
    return explode(" ", fgets($fh));
}
```

And instead of getting an array of values from a line,
and then assigning to variables by indexes,
you can benefit from [array unpacking](http://portfolio.planetjon.ca/2011/07/14/array-unpacking-in-php/), like this:

```
$input = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
list(, $testCount) = read_line_as_array($input);

$arr = read_line_as_array($input);
for ($i = 0; $i < $testCount; $i++)
{
    list($start, $end) = read_line_as_array($input);
    $min = $arr[$start];
    for ($j = $start + 1; $j <= $end; $j++)
    {
        if ($arr[$j] < $min) {
            $min = $arr[$j];
        }
    }
    echo $min . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Notice how I read into the `$start` and `$end` variables directly,
no need for temporary variables to store the line.

I also dropped all the `intval` calls,
simply because my test cases work just fine without it.
If it turns out to be necessary,
you can simply improve on `read_line_as_array` to return proper integers,
and then the rest of the code will work just fine.

Another improvement I did is calculating the `$min` in a single pass and without a temporary array:
the original code makes one pass to create a temporary array,
and then calls `min(...)` on it, which is a second pass.

Last but not least,
I cleaned up the variable names.
`$i` and `$j` could be better,
but they are acceptable as simple loop variables.
(The `$i` and `$j` had a different meaning in the original code,
and not used as loop variables,
in which case they were not acceptable names.)